# Excel: Macro Enabled Template Reference Error

Tags: vba, excel, templates, macros

I have a template named MorningReport.xltm
I have a macro that copies data from a file and pastes it into the file.  The problem is that when the user opens the file, it renames it to MorningReport1 and I can't figure out what the file extension is on that new one?  When I go to run the macro, it can't find the file (b/c I am assuming I am not putting the right extension on it).  Any solutions or insight into how template referencing works or how to outright solve my problem would be fantastic!

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a `Worksheet Open` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It doesn't have an extension.**

Just as a new blank workbook is called **Book1** and not **Book1.xlsx** or **Book1.xlsm** or **Book1.xlsb** without saving the workbook, your template has created a new, blank workbook based on the .xltm template. It will not have an associated extension until it has been saved as one of the workbook [XlFileFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx)s.

This behavior can be verified by going into the VBE and typing `?thisworkbook.name` into the [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx).

Comment: Perfect!  Solved my problem!  Just leave off the file extension and it references just fine!  Many thanks!